# Execute a php command from another php file

Tags: php, xcode, curl, ssh

I having a simple problem, I guess.
I am working on an iPhone app which I can send ASIHTTPRequest to my php server (with go daddy). The php script then gets the command and run like:

```
$this->pdo->beginTransaction();
//do some other simple works
exec ('/usr/local/bin/php -f /path/to/my/script/test.php') ;
$this->pdo->commit();
```

which is suppose to run another php file within my own server (dedicated)!!! But it does NOT do anything. It does work with curl_exec() though, but I want to use another method which I can put it to work in the background server.

My planning was that I want to send too many APNS (notification) but instead of waiting for the whole list to be done, it is better to get back and let the work done in the background!! How can I do that.

When I got connected using SSH command line. I can easily call "test.php" and it works so fine. But I can not do the same thing from the above php code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHP Include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)? That will run the script.
Put something like this inside an IF Statement.

```
include 'YourPage.php';
```

Comment: What if 'YourPage.php' file needs parameter inputs (as arguments) to fire up. How to enter these. Thanks;

Comment: Set that as variables before the include. They can they be used within the include file. Using includes basically makes it all one single PHP files to the server to some extent.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this was your answer please mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that GoDaddy might not allow exec() to be run for security purposes.